# How to delete DataGridView row on keyBoard Delete button Click?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Hei what i did so far ..Now using contextmenu i can able to delete row of my grid

```
 private void dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_IsLocked != true)
        {
            dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute.ContextMenuStrip = AttributecontextMenuForDelete;


            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                DataGridView current = (DataGridView)sender;
                var hti = dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute.ClearSelection();
                dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;

            }

        }
    }

    private void AttributecontextMenuForDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_IsLocked != true)
        {
            Int32 rowToDelete = dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            var AttributeTypeId = dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute.Rows[rowToDelete].Cells["ccAttributeId"].Value.ToString();

            PersonController obj = new PersonController();
            List<EmploymentAttribute> _type = new List<EmploymentAttribute>();
            //var id=_type.Where(q=>q.Name==).Select(p=>p.TypeId)
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to mark this attribute as deleted", " ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                obj.DeleteAttributeById(Convert.ToInt32(AttributeTypeId));
                dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
                dataGridViewEmploymentAttribute.ClearSelection();
                MessageBox.Show("Attribute deleted successfully");
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //do something else
            }
        }
    }
```

But problem is that client's requirement is like that,on selection any row..if you click delete button of keyboard it shuold delete that row..

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the ProcessCmdKey override

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        // Delete Key - Delete Selected Row!
        if (keyData == Keys.Delete)
        {
            DeleteSelectedRow();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: No need to setup anything extra, with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the problem with scripting the **KeyDown** event?

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) Console.Beep();
    }
```

If indeed you are in editing mode you can use the **PreviewKeyDown** event:

```
private void dgv_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) Console.Beep();
}
```

Of course this may surprise users..!

You must enable **KeyPreview** for the **form** as well. If that's a problem, you can enable and disable KeyPreview in the **Enter** and **Leave** events of the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgv1_KeyDown(Object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.key==Key.Delete)
 {
               //check here whether row is selected or not and remove that one
        }
}
```

It would be helpful to you...